# Generate models in doctrine2

Tags: database, model, doctrine-orm

In doctrine1 it was possible to generate-models-db. How to do that in doctrine2 from cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up implementing new command https://github.com/umpirsky/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/GenerateEntitiesDbCommand.php :)

Later, I realized  you can

```
php doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database yml /path/to/mapping-path-converted-to-yml
```